# Convert Word 6.0 to Word 2003 programatically

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

With the latest security update from MS 
[Security](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/ms09-073.mspx)

Existing word templates documents could not be loaded and they  started throwing exceptions each time we load.
We would like to convert the existing Word 6.0 to Word 2003 programmatically or by using a tool.

How do we convert using .NET? Or any existing MS Tool
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537157(office.11).aspx#officevstocsharpdev_passingparameterstoword) on how to programmatically hit Word's object model.  Once you get that down, it should be a simple matter of writing a program to get Word to open a file and then perform a "Save As" for every file you have.

Answer (score 0):

your other option is to use OpenOffice in a scripted way.